# A bit confused about use of localStorage or cookies

Tags: node.js, cookies, jwt

So, I read in multiple articles that localStorage, or sessionStorage, is more "affected" by xss/csrf injection than cookies.

First: this is true?

I know that I could use cookie to check xsrf validation.

I have a node js server, and a react js frontend. And, to not miss anything, I'm using the localStorage to store the JWT (my access token). This is really bad, for what I understood by reading.

Now: I want that my website will be really safe, and here I'm confused.

Should I leave the use of JWT or could I store my JWT in a secure cookie? And then add some extra-cookies about x-srf, xss?

Or should I use a cookie-session instead of jwt?

I don't want use anymore the localStorage (or sessionStorage) after the readings of this afternoon.

And if I don't use JWT, how could I store (in encrypted way) the info in the cookie-session? And I must create the cookie in the front-end or send the cookie value from the server to the client and then set a cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of using Cookies is that you can mark cookies are being inaccessible by javascript.

This is a benefit over LocalStorage, because LocalStorage is always accessible by javascript. The security implication of LocalStorage is that *IF* you have an XSS security problem, an attacker can obtain the token.

However, if you use cookies it *may* also be possible for an attacker to exploit, *IF* you have a CSRF security problem. Or, if you have an XSS problem it might still be possible for an attacker to use the session if they can directly talk to the API.

There's no right answer here, but either cookies or Localstorage are normally a 'good enough' option. Just try to stick to other security best practices. Always be aware of XSS problems and use super strict SCP policies. This paragraph is not comprehensive. OWASP has good security guides.

Comment: So, can I store a JWT in a cookie? And the use this cookie for all validation?

Comment: @Stackedo I updated my answer slightly. Some people do indeed store JWT in a cookie.